# Maven dependency in Local Repository but not being picked up

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

The dependency I'm using is for Oracle which, reading from another post, is not included in the default maven repo due to legal issues. For this reason I've added the dependency to my local repo using:

```
 mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/<myname>/development/Libraries/ojdbc6.jar 
     -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```

My problem is that maven is attempting to pull the file from the default remote repo and failing although it was my understanding that the local repo is checked first.

My install of maven is the default version packaged with STS (basically Eclipse).

Kind Regards,

Justin

Comment: Does the problem occur when you run maven from Eclipse? Or in the command line too? It is possible that Eclipse does not know the path to your local repo?

Answer (score 0):

Checking whether the jar got properly installed in your local repository might help. If you navigate to the `.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.03/` you should find the jar present there.

Comment: I'm running into this exact problem as well (on Ubuntu). Using mvn from command line. Both the jar and the pom exist in my local repo. Pom contents look good.

Answer (score 0):

if this problem is present, i can suggest you to select the Offline option on maven uptade project. Whith this option enabled, the maven install search for local repository.